# Select two tables in one query PDO

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I'v spent already a few hours to figure out this query but no result,

I'm actually new in PDO I used to do MYSQL but I saw here on stackoverflow that I have to change to PDO because MYSQL will be disabled soon,

So now to my question, I want to select two different tables with no relations one to other in one query like this,

```
$query = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM table1; SELECT * FROM table2");
//rest of query,
```

How do I do that?

Comment: MySQL will be disabled? MySQL is the database system you're working with. And PDO works with MySQL, too.

Comment: I don't really see what the purpose of simultaneously quering two unrelated tables might be, not to mention the mess this causes in the result dtaset.

Comment: @ShogunArts.de he means the old and deprecated `mysql_` php extension, not the DBMS.

Comment: @ShogunArts.de sorry, I mean to say that `mysql_query()` will be disabled

Comment: If you write a query and it gives you the resultset you expect in the MySQL query window/CLI interface, you can run it against a PDO object and it will give you the same results each and every time. Get your query right, then pass it to the PDO object and you will get the right data back.

Comment: Ahhh okay, just a missunderstanding. Than just do two queries. And a tip. Use alway $query = $dbh->prepare('SQL') and than $query ->execute instead of only query.

Comment: @ShogunArts.de Thank you, just one question, in the execute function what do I need to do? I need to make an array?

Comment: Nothing, only `$query->execute();`. After this you can fetch your data (if SELECT). You just do one line of code into two but you're on the save side against sql injection.

Comment: @ShogunArts.de Thank you very much, please post it as an answer so I should be able to accept it

Comment: What exactly? The tip using prepare and than execute or to do two queries instead of one? ^^

Comment: @ShogunArts.de its okay, I just mind thats only a tip :), lol

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like how you'd do it with vanilla SQL:

```
$query = $dbh->query("SELECT * FROM table1, table2");
```

Comment: No idea. Are the tables empty?

Comment: No its full, I used it with mySQL

Comment: That query will do a hideous cartesian join on the two tables and it certainly will result in every row in table1 being matched with every row in table2. You can't get an empty resultset if the tables have data.

Answer (score 0):

Or use JOIN

SELECT t1.id, t2.name FROM users AS t1 JOIN persons AS t2 ON t1.id = t2.id;

Comment: The has no relationship, so I cant do a join

Comment: @itsme if there's no relationship between the two tables, then why are you selecting them with a single query?

Comment: Because I need to select them both and I dont want to do two different query's, instead I want it to be in one query

Comment: itsme, The only way to do it is with a horrid cartesian as @MattBall showed you above.